# MarkdownSharp & GitHub syntax for C# code

Tags: c#, github, markdown, markdownsharp

Is there a way to get MarkdownSharp (I'm using the [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MarkdownSharp)) to handle '[GitHub flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) (GFM)' and especially syntax highlighting of c# code, which (in GFM) is written like this:

````
```c#
//my code.....
```
````

So, if I pass Markdown formatted content to MarkDownSharp, containg a C# code block (as above) I want it to generate syntax highlighted html for that c# code. Any ideas? I know I can use the supported 4 spaces to indicate a code block, but again, I'm seeking a solution for getting it to support GitHub flavored Markdown.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this same problem, but I specifically need the github table support. I haven't found any existing library that seems to do it. same problem as discussed [here](https://github.com/Wheelies/MarkdownLog/issues/4)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the result: https://github.com/danielwertheim/kiwi/wiki/Use-with-Asp.Net-MVC

//D

Answer (score 37):

I have made some light modifications to MarkdownSharp that will transform github flavored fenced code blocks

https://github.com/KyleGobel/MarkdownSharp-GithubCodeBlocks

````
```cs
Console.WriteLine("Fenced code blocks ftw!");
```
````

Would become

```
<pre><code class='language-cs'>
Console.WriteLine("Fenced code blocks ftw!");
</code></pre>
```

It handles the cases I needed to use, there are probably lots of edge cases though, feel free to fork/change/modify/pull request.  Markdown sharp has plenty of comments and is all only one file, so it's not too bad to modify.

Answer (score 4):

As one can read in this [post](https://github.com/blog/832-rolling-out-the-redcarpet), GitHub relies on [RedCarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) to render Markdown syntax.

However, Vicent Marti ([Sundown](https://github.com/vmg/sundown) (ex-Upskirt) and RedCarpet maintainer) [states](https://github.com/blog/832-rolling-out-the-redcarpet#comment-12081) that the syntax highlighting is specifically handled by [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), a python library.

Back to your concern, I can think of several options to benefit from syntax highlighting from C#:

- Try and build a compiled managed version of Pygments [source code](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src) thanks to [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) (*"IronPython’s Hosting APIs can be used to compile Python scripts into DLLs, console executables, or Windows executables."*)
- Port Pygment to C#
- Use a different syntax highlighting product (for instance, [ColorCode](http://colorcode.codeplex.com/) which is used by Codeplex...)

Then either:

- Fork MarkDownSharp to make it accept plug-ins
- Similarly to what GitHub does, use the managed syntax highlighting product and post process the Html generated by MarkDownSharp

By the way, as a MarkDown alternative, you might want to consider [Moonshine](https://github.com/brandonc/moonshine), a managed wrapper on top of Sundown which is said to be *"at least 20x faster than MarkdownSharp when run against MarkdownSharp's own benchmark app."*

Comment: I actually have done it both. Made a spike with Pygments using IronPython and C# but that route brings to many dependencies. The solution was Pre and Post processing with MarkdownSharp and ColorCode. I'm putting it out on GitHub and NuGet.

Comment: Some of these links are now broken, @nulltoken.

Comment: @AdamKDean The sundown link is now fixed.