# Using github-flavored markdown in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, github-flavored-markdown

I'm working on a website in C# using ASP.NET MVC and am seriously considering markdown for some pieces (notably static pages and blog posts), as it seems a lot easier to work with than HTML. Some posts will have C# code embedded in them. Is there a way to get the goodness of github-flavored markdown to work in a c# app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at this GitHub project.

https://github.com/danielwertheim/kiwi/wiki/Use-with-Asp.Net-MVC

which was sourced from this SO question

[MarkdownSharp & GitHub syntax for C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8210974/1593273)