# Unity Firebase Realtime Database returning "old" data

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Unity SDK for Firebase Realtime Database. Most of the time it works perfectly. However, sometimes it returns old data for queries. Sometimes its just the one right before last update, sometimes, I'm not even sure how many updates in between its been.

You can see my DB reference below, note the `levelDepth, keyCount, keysAquiredLevels, gold, currentLevelCompleted` values.

[image]

Below, is an image of the raw response I get in Unity when using `var response = await databaseReference.GetValueAsync();` You'll notice all those properties are different from a previous update.

[image]

This code works most of the time, I really have to hammer it 10-20 times to reproduce this issue, however it happens! and I am not sure why.

I've set `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(false);` and I attempted to set `keepSync` to both true and false, but the issue still happens.

```cs
    void Start()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(false);
        Firebase.AppOptions options = AppOptions.LoadFromJsonConfig(firebaseOptions.text);
        FirebaseApp.Create(options);
    }

    public static async Task<CurrentLevelConfig> GetCurrentLevelConfig()
    {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
                                                                        .RootReference
                                                                        .Child("users")
                                                                        .Child(FirebaseConfig.user.UserId)
                                                                        .Child("currentLevelConfig");

        var response = await databaseReference.GetValueAsync();
        if (response.Exists)
        {
            CurrentLevelConfig config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentLevelConfig>(response.GetRawJsonValue());
            Debug.Log("Got current level config!");
            return config;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATING WITH MORE SCREENSHOTS**
It seems the resolution for adding `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()` did not fix the issue. As its an intermittent issue, it took some time to reproduce. Here are additional screenshots of the raw database snapshot showing different data than what the console shows. You will see that the highlighted fields reflect completely different values.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try running the same query but instead of awaiting the result pass a callback using [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension#continuewithonmainthread) as shown in [Retrieving Data - Read Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#read_data_once)

To elaborate, are you running this query on a thread you are spawning? It's possible this may be a race condition.

UPDATE with the prospective solution from my subsequent comment:

Call [FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app#checkandfixdependenciesasync) before running all Firebase functionality. Use a callback and then run FirebaseApp.Create.

An example of doing this using the callback method and DefaultInstance (which calls Create() under the hood) can be seen in [Add Firebase to your Unity Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#confirm-google-play-version).

Comment: I updated as you suggested, and although it seems to be the documented approach, I am still experiencing the issue. Again its not every time which is why I could understand your thought of a race condition, but I don't believe it is one. To clarify, this is on a fresh launch of the app, so the only local previous data would be from an empty model with default values. My game is loading the correct once it gets data from Firebase, its just that Firebase is feeding me the wrong data. So I believe await is working property.

Comment: Ahh interesting. Is there a chance you could post the code where you are initializing Firebase and getting the database reference in your code?

Comment: added code to question above

Comment: Thank you much for adding the code. Are you calling [FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app#checkandfixdependenciesasync) before running all Firebase functionality?

If not, please try doing so, awaiting the method or using a call back **and then**  running FirebaseApp.Create.

An example of doing this using the callback method and DefaultInstance (which calls `Create()` under the hood) can be seen in [Add Firebase to your Unity Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#confirm-google-play-version).

Comment: Additionally: when posting code to stackoverflow, if you want to include code coloring/syntax highlighting, consider including the code for the language in the opening "```" as shown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23595911/18173626

Comment: Thanks @joe this seemed to do the trick. It did seem to be an intermittent issue before so I'll keep testing but as of now I'm no longer able to reproduce. Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: sorry for the back and forth here. although it did seem to happen less for a day or two, the issue is still there. updating first post with more screenshots.

Comment: No problem,

Please post more of the calling code showing how/when you are calling `GetCurrentLevelConfig ` and how you are ensuring it is not called before initialization has completed.

If possible please just post as much of the methods and members as are relevant as possible (while redacting anything sensitive).